# How do I unzip a password protected file with Deflate64 compression? I have the password already. In python or vb.net

Tags: unzip

So I have a series of thousands of .zip files that need to be opened.
They are password protected, but I have the passwords.

Trying to automate the opening of these. the deflate64 issue is causing a lot of pain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So deflate64 is proprietary which is annoying as that stops you from using the normal zipfile library in python. As a workaround i typically make a subprocess call to 7zip or similar. So something like:

```
import subprocess, sys
subprocess.Popen(["7z", "e", f"{filename}", f"-o{destination}", "-y" "-p" password])
```

Then naturally just run that in a loop over your files. Depending on how they are laid out you might want to just glob everything in a directory or pipe them via stdin etc.

Often tasks like this are well suited to shell scripts so you might want to consider that, I'm not a windows user but i think something like the following script would work as well:

```
@echo off
set pass=[password]
set folder=[folder]

for /R "%folder%" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "C:\somedirectory\7z.exe" x -p%pass% -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" 
)
```